# Is AppCompat possible to ignore on API 23+?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-appcompat, androidx

I am developing an Android Project from scratch that has min 23 API level and uses AndroidX. When I complete the XML layouts (for ex. simple activity_layout) there is options to pick like between `TextView` & `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView`.

1. Is `TextView` targeting AndroidX?
2. If yes, can I ignore using `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView` or other `AppCompat` component if I target min 23 API level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Is TextView targeting AndroidX?**

The question in not clear but the class `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView` extends `android.widget.TextView`.

You can check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatTextView).

> A TextView which supports compatible features on older versions of the platform.

Also:

> This will automatically be used when you use `TextView` in your layouts and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

Then.

> **If yes, can I ignore using androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView or other AppCompat component if I target min 23 API level?**

You can ignore this view if you are using the `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:x.y.z` library.

Answer (score 3):

from the standard android documentation for AppCompatTextView:

> This will automatically be used when you use TextView in your layouts
>   and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You
>   should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

taken from here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextView , so yes, you can just use `TextView` as long as your activity extends `AppCompatActivity`

---

As pointed out by @Gabriele Mariotti (thank you to him) you should check out the documentation here https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatTextView for more information regarding androidx `AppCompatTextView` documentation specifically.

The androidX documentation states the following regarding an `AppCompatTextView`:

> This will automatically be used when you use TextView in your layouts
>   and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You
>   should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views

an exact duplicate of the standard android documentation.

---

My initial answer only made use of this : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat to check for any known limitations or history regarding androidx `AppCompatTextView`

I assumed that:

> Like the Support Library, AndroidX ships separately from the Android
>   OS and provides backwards-compatibility across Android releases.
>   AndroidX fully replaces the Support Library by providing feature
>   parity and new libraries.

taken from https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx would be sufficient to make that assumption, +1 to him for the help :)